# Get multiple variables from table and store them in some variables

Tags: sql, sql-server

For this example, the query and result are:
Query:

```
select name from sys.parameters where object_id = @@PROCID;
```

Result:

```
name
@BKP_TBL
@Filter
```

I want to store the actual value of `@BKP_TBL` and `@Filter` in another variable. Therefore, I am using `string_agg` to aggregate the result into a single row and store it in new variable as shown below:

```
    DECLARE @PARAMS_DER VARCHAR(MAX);
    select @PARAMS_DER = string_agg(name,'+')   from sys.parameters where object_id = @@PROCID group by object_id;
```

The problem is that `@PARAMS_DER` is storing `@BKP_TBL+@Filter` instead of their values.

Comment: Your query returns 2 rows, how do you want to store that in a variable? Maybe you want a table variable?

Comment: I am thinking something like this:
select @PARAMS_DER = string_agg(name,'+')   from sys.parameters where object_id = @@PROCID group by object_id;
But the problem is, new variable is storing variable names instead of actual values.

Value of PARAMS_DER is @BKP_TBL+@Filter

Comment: A "VARHCAR" (I assume you mean `varchar`) is a **scalar** variable. It can store one value, and one value only. If you want to store more, you need to use a table type variable and `INSERT` the values into it.

Comment: You want to do that inside a procedure? Otherwise parameters do not have values.

Comment: Yes. I am doing this inside procedure.
Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to do. You are after some generic code that can be put into any stored proc and that will look up the parameters of the proc from the system tables and then create a concatenated string with the value that was passed for all those params? If so I don't think that is possible. You would need dynamic SQL to reference the parameter names once you've found them out and then the parameters from the outer proc will be out of scope.